# Is there a way to plot a value calculated with a mathematical formula?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

Let's imagine I have this command

```
library(ggpubr)
ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "supp", y = "len",
          color = "supp", palette = "jco",
          add = "jitter")
p + stat_compare_means(method = "t.test")
```

I would like to plot y values as a calculated value: **2^len** and to leave compare means on **len** original values.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether I got you right but you can add a new column with the calculated value to your data, use this new var inside `ggboxplot`, while passing the orginal variable to `stat_compare_means` via the `mapping` :

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
ToothGrowth$len2 <- 2^ToothGrowth$len
ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "supp", y = "len2",
          color = "supp", palette = "jco",
          add = "jitter") +
  stat_compare_means(aes(x = supp, y = len, color = supp), method = "t.test")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Stefan, that's indeed what I needed.

An additional question, if you consider this code

```
ggbarplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len", add = "mean_se",
          color = "supp", palette = "jco", 
          position = position_dodge(0.8))+
  stat_compare_means(aes(group = supp), label = "p.signif", label.y = 29)
```

I would like to compare both "supp" groups with the same reference group (i.e. "0.5"), as to have a distinct p.signif label on each bar.

Any suggestion?